# Qual è il significato di "dare senso", "fare senso" o "una mossa di senso" in questi brani?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto:

> Stava male, in particolare gli dolevano i polmoni, pareva si sfregassero l’uno contro l’altro con punte
>   fattesi da cartilagine in metallo, e **gli davano senso** e sofferenza.

Più avanti nel libro questo vocabolo, "senso", appare di nuovo in contesti che a me sembra possano essere simili:

> Masticava con violenza, la fetta di lardo era cosí
>   spessa e ricca che a Milton **faceva quasi senso** incontrarla coi denti pur dopo l’alto spessore del pane.
>
> La maestra faceva ancora qualche **mossa di sofferenza o di senso** e la gonna le montò
>   piú su, ora mostrava le giarrettiere.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "senso" in queste espressioni: "dare senso", "fare senso", una "mossa di senso".  Si riferiscono all'accezione **2 b** del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/senso/)?

> L’avvertimento di sensazioni interne, di natura fisica o, talora, psichica, spec. se non ben definite: *avvertire un s. di fame; provare un s. di benessere, di malessere, di stanchezza, di pesantezza alla testa, di languore allo stomaco, d’amaro in bocca,* ecc.

Comment: *Fare senso* è un'espressione idiomatica che significa essere disgustoso, specie in un modo spiacevole, vedi ad esempio qui: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/S/senso.shtml#. Direi che *senso* nelle altre espressioni ha un significato simile, magari con una punta in più di sofferenza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direi che in tutti e tre i casi il significato è più quello indicato nella accezione 3 a della voce citata del dizionario Treccani, ovvero:

> uno stato d’animo, una sensazione, un atteggiamento psichico: *sentiva dentro di sé come un s. di vuoto; la sua partenza ha lasciato in tutti noi un s. di rimpianto; provare un s. di tristezza, d’amarezza, di sconforto*, ecc. Molto com. nell’uso fam. l’espressione *fare senso*, di cosa che produce una impressione forte e non gradevole (simile a disgusto o ripugnanza) o un turbamento psichico in genere: *vedergli perdere tutto quel sangue mi faceva senso; spettacoli di miseria che fanno senso*.